# How to Add HTML in controller Codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

My content controller in codeIgniter:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class AutoLoadDiv extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('ngoding/AutoLoad');
    }

    public function getData() {

        $this->load->library('table');
        $err = file_get_contents("application\logs\log.php");
        $filestr = preg_replace(array('/(^|\R)ERROR\s*-\s*/', '/(^|\R)(.*?)\s*-->\s*/'), array('$1', '$1$2 '), $err);
        $arraySpacing = nl2br($filestr);
        $arr = explode("\n", $arraySpacing);

        for ($i = count($arr)-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
            echo "<html><body><table><tr><td>$arr[$i];</td></tr></table></body>/html>";
        }
      }
  }
```

I have a problem make table in controller , I want to print a table like this:

[image]

I have view :

https://codeshare.io/GqyWmk

Comment: You need to re-evaluate your method of using this framework, under no circumstance should you ever have to put html in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

To print table like in the image you need to change your code like this.

Assuming you have only 4 column in the file:

```
   $output = "<html><body><table>"; // Keep this outside for loop to print only once.


   var $j = 0;
   for ($i = count($arr)-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {

      if ($j % 4 == 0) {
          $output.="<tr>";
      }
      $output.="<td>$arr[$i]</td>"; // Adding new row in your output varible.
      if ($j % 4 == 0) {
         $output.="</tr>";
      }
     ++$j;
     }
        $output.="</table></body>/html>"; // This should also be outside because you want to close table, body and html only once.
        echo $output; // Printing your final data.
```

You can modify this code as per your requirement;

Comment: If there are fix no of columns then you can add if condition to create new row.

Comment: how to add style in controller to make border table ?

Comment: Your first code work print like this : https://ibb.co/idCyjK , but I want add background color every row is different like this : https://ibb.co/jUn9rz how make background color every line different ?

Comment: Have you tried the above code? Do you want to color odd and even rows only?